# Adding jQuery and javascript in URI (as null)

Tags: javascript, security, uri

This is a security question.
My boss has asked me to find (and show a prototype) of possible hacks over the site and I am over one.

There is an input box on the page and using URI javascript (also know as void or null script) , I have to include a javascript file and jquery file (for the ease of presentation). The following code did not work.

```
javascript:{{ 
var e=document.createElement("script"); 
alert("Hello World");
e.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js";e.type="text/javascript"; 
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);
};}
```

(After uri encoding) I did get "Hello World" alert box but I was not able to find the script while using 'inspect element' in chrome. or otherwise no script ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right - you want to include to add new JavaScript to the page. This is my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662845/is-it-possible-to-unite-several-async-social-button-loaders-into-one/6663892#6663892)

And about the inspect element - right click on the element and it is the last one of the menu.

Comment: No, there is no bug - look at the result [here](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/5610/screenshotoja.png)

Comment: well thats wierd cause when I tried it through URI, only twitter was added (maybe it was because I included a local file in the middle).